# React: Cannot read property 'getWeather' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to figure out where this type error is coming from but I can't seem to pinpoint it. Perhaps I'm missing an important concept of React.

I have a Weather class in React like:

```
class Weather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cityName: "San Francisco",
      temp: null,
    }
  }

  getWeather(city) {
    // does fetch request to openweathermap.org
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getWeather(this.state.cityName);
    // this.state.cityName is updated as the user types
  }
}
```

the problem is whenever I click the submit button I get an error about my getWeather function saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWeather' of undefined

Any recommendations? I tried binding the getWeather function but it didn't help.

Comment: Likely an issue with handleSubmit not being bound. Can you show us where handleSubmit is being used?

Comment: @NicholasTower that's exactly it. Daniel below helped me get that going. Not sure how I missed that but like I said below my component is way bigger than my example shows, so I guess "easily" overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind both `getWeather` and `handleSubmit`:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cityName: "San Francisco",
      temp: null,
    }

    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: This was it. I have no idea how I forgot to also bind handleSubmit. The component is bigger than I made it out to be with this code so I totally overlooked that. I had a feeling a binding was off based on the error and you figured it out in an instant. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

In your case `this` relates to element, not class. Use arrow function.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getWeather(this.state.cityName);
    // this.state.cityName is updated as the user types
  }
```